# How to get a text from a string with symbol using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get variable with \ symbol from a string.but not working.

```
var prevLink='../my-test-pack/mvc';

var actLink=prevLink.remove('..').remove('/').join('\');

console.log(actLink);

//output actLink should be like actLink='\my-test-pack\mvc';
```

prevLink dynamically will change like

```
var prevLink='../my-test-pack/mvc/svc'; or var prevLink='../my-test-pack/mvc/skg';
```

but my output should be like

```
    actLink='\my-test-pack\mvc\svc'; or actLink='\my-test-pack\mvc\skg';
```

How to get that?Anyone can help to get this value?

Comment: You are using `/` in `prevLink`

Comment: @DominikMatis:  Yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try (this will also change `/` to `\` as you wished

```js
var prevLink='../my-test-pack/mvc';
var actLink=prevLink.replace(/\//g, "\\").split("..")[1];
console.log(actLink)
```

Comment: You can mark it as correct if it's what you wanted. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, strings have no `remove()` method. Use `replace()` instead. Secondly, you need to `split()` the string before you `join()` it again. Also note that you need to escape the `\` as it has a special meaning in JS:

```js
var prevLink = '../my-test-pack/mvc';
var actLink = prevLink.replace('..', '').split('/').join('\\');
console.log(actLink);
```